# ARR proxy to tomcat with SSL forced

Tags: tomcat, iis, ssl, proxy, arr

I am having problems getting an AAR reverse proxy server to talk to a tomcat server over ssl on the backend. 
server1.com listens on port 443 with a godaddy ssl cert. This is the ARR server 192.168.1.1
server2.com listens on port 8443 with self signed cert. This is the Tomcat server 192.168.1.11

Here is the url rewrite rule

Here is the server farm config

Here is the FailedReqLogFiles show this when attempting to access the server1 over https [image]

Can anybody point me in the right direction? I dont have access to the Tomcat server so all magic will have to happen on the IIS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to ignore all ssl errors between the AAR and Tomcat install by following this page and that did the trick. 
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/arr-support-added-for-winhttpoptionsecurityflags

```
reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\Application Request Routing\Parameters" /v SecureConnectionIgnoreFlags /t REG_DWORD /d 3300
```

I rebooted before I even attempted to connect. Not sure if that was necessary or not. I just needed some coffee.